# "Undefined reference to" using libxml2 in C with Eclipse

Tags: c, xml, eclipse, libxml2

I'm trying to compilate a C program(Appendix C of this [pdf](http://xmlsoft.org/tutorial/xmltutorial.pdf)) using libxml2 in Eclipse.

Looks like the program recognize the library but not the functions of the headers(i.e. recognize < xmlstring.h > but not the function xmlStrcmp)

This is a screenshot of my eclipse plattform: http://goo.gl/kOdvZB

(This is my first post so I dont have reputation to post images, sorry u.u):

What could be the problem here?
What am I doing wrong?

I don't know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: Why have you tagged this c++?

Comment: I've changed it, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remember to link against the library?  The "undefined reference" error is a linker error which means that the symbol you requested doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm new doing this, could you tell me how can I do that, please?

Comment: I solved my problem, I just need to link. Thanks.

Comment: Now I have a "First defined here" error

Comment: Now I have a "First defined here" error
Screenshoot : http://goo.gl/MVUY57
Thanks for help.